# Can I found a contact photo in Android 6.0?

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, contact-photo

I want to add a photo to contact. So I found the person I want to add photo. And I click the camera icon then it took me to the camera and I took a photo of him. After that it crop the photo into square. However I cannot found the contact photo and I cannot even found this photo in my phone. So can I find this photo in my phone? or any cache of this photo in my camera application?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

- The photo is indeed saved but in a folder which is set not to display media in your multimedia apps like gallery, music etc (contains the .nomedia file). You need to look it up somewhere on your storage using a file manager app instead of gallery.
- The photo is saved in the contact you associated it with, on your Google account. Meaning the photo itself when shot, was saved in the contact, and then the file was deleted from the storage.

I think the 2nd possibility is probably what happened, because if you wanted to take a photo and save it on your phone, you would have taken it with a camera app, not through contacts.